# Generic vcxproj.filters for all my visual studio 2013 projects

Tags: visual-studio, vcxproj

Is it possible to create only one vcxproj.filters file for all the Visual studio C/C++ projects?

I have created many vcxproj files manually where I have extracted few common properties to few other project files which I import in the manually created vcxproj files. Now I am adding these vcxproj files to a solution. As there are no filter files the files are not organized under the project when I see in the solution. I want to create a generic *.vcxproj.filters for all the project something like below. Is it even possible to do so?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Filter Include="Source Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{C8062205-5C8A-482C-B951-6A170BB4E950}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>cpp;c;cc;cxx;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx</Extensions>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="Header Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{4C83BCBB-DB7D-48AB-BE10-CEDED3FA4444}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>h;hh;hpp;hxx;hm;inl;inc;xsd</Extensions>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="Resource Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{013D88EE-F154-4F5A-B34A-A11987AC8F67}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>rc;ico;cur;bmp;dlg;rc2;rct;bin;rgs;gif;jpg;jpeg;jpe;resx;tiff;tif;png;wav;mfcribbon-ms</Extensions>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="Definition Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{81DFBEC0-6CAB-489A-971C-33D6FD792A98}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>def</Extensions>
    </Filter>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The .filters file for a new project is generated by the project wizard.  Pretty whacko in C++, it is done in JavaScript.  I think you need to edit C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\VCWizards\1033\common.js (1033 for English, adjust for your language), SetupFilters() function.  Be careful, make backups.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant, I would leave that as it is and create individual filter files for each project.